# Boost serialization example error

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I read the example and I try to run the following code:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

```
#include <fstream>

// include headers that implement a archive in simple text format
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// gps coordinate
//
// illustrates serialization for a simple type
//

class gps_position {
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    // When the class Archive corresponds to an output archive, the
    // & operator is defined similar to <<.  Likewise, when the class Archive
    // is a type of input archive the & operator is defined similar to >>.

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & degrees;
        ar & minutes;
        ar & seconds;
    }
    int degrees;
    int minutes;
    float seconds;
public:

    gps_position() {
    };

    gps_position(int d, int m, float s) :
    degrees(d), minutes(m), seconds(s) {
    }
};

int main() {
    // create and open a character archive for output
    std::ofstream ofs("filename");

    // create class instance
    const gps_position g(35, 59, 24.567f);

    // save data to archive
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        // write class instance to archive
        oa << g;
        // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
    }

    // ... some time later restore the class instance to its orginal state
    gps_position newg;
    {
        // create and open an archive for input
        std::ifstream ifs("filename");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        // read class state from archive
        ia >> newg;
        // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And I get the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
  what():  output stream error

RUN FINISHED; Aborted; core dumped; real time: 100ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Comment: does the user this code is run as have the permissions to create and write to a file in the current working directory ?

Comment: Maybe you should check if your file was opened with `if (ifs.good())`

Comment: When run code, I see a new file "filename" but the file is blank. Do you run it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copy-pasted the code, compiled, ran, no-problem.  Based on this and your error message, I'm guessing you have a system problem.  Probably something is preventing you from writing your file.  The most likely culprit is a permission error.  If you were writing a large file I might guess disk full, but it seems unlikely you're that full up.

Try running the executable somewhere else, or hard coding a path to somewhere you have write permissions.   Try a simple hellow world with ofstream to see if you can create and write a file.

Comment: Also consider whether you're building against the same version of the library that's found at runtime

Comment: When run code, I see a new file "filename" but the file is blank and I tried to in other directory. What is your boost version? I'm using Boost 1.58 and Netbeans to compile.

Comment: Hi.  Sorry if this sounds pedantic, but netbeans is an ide, not a compiler.  Somehwhere it is calling a compiler -- probably g++, but maybe clang.  I compiled with g++ but I doubt that's the issue.   Boost version is the same, so I don't think that's the issue.  Try erasing the file and running again -- same behavior?   Given your behavior, Sehe's suggestion may be the winner.

Comment: Thanks for you support, I mean g++ . I try some time but I still got error, what is command you use to compile?

Comment: I built from the command line "g++ temp.cpp -lboost_serialization".   Did you try doing a simple write to file operation (e.g. ofstream  of("test.txt"); of << "some test text";)?  If that works and you can read the line in the file, it's probabaly a difference between compile and runtime linking like Sehe suggested.

Comment: Hi, my mistake is to have 2 different library boost version 1.55 and 1.58. So, I delete the old version and everything is okie :)

Comment: These things happen.    Much of becoming a good programmer is accumulating knowledge of how things go wrong.  Vote up Sehe's comment since he originally thought of the possibility.

Comment: In my case, I was trying to create a file inside of a subfolder. STL has no ability to automatically create folders.